# Angular seems to fire on its own

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I have a `$http.put` function that updates my database, this happens on a button click. After I update the database once, and stay on the page, with no interaction at all the update function gets called and will update the database with the last information that was inputted.

I've triple checked my code, there is only one occurrence of my update function being called. And the `$http.put` is inside `$scope.update` that is an anonymous function that calls the `$http.put`.

If I update information and then leave the page, and then come back the function does not fire on it's own.

Here is my Github for the project. I will pull out any specific code that you want to see, but I'm not sure what to show because there are 4 files involved. Those files are

```
(client/scripts/app.js)
(routes/products.js)
(public/views/routes/adminIndex.html)
(public/views/routes/modProduct.html)
```

[Code is Here](https://github.com/VinceJones/basementIdeas)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `console.trace()` just before the `$http` call to see what is calling it.

You can also use the developper console of your browser and add a breakpoint that will stop the code execution and let you inspect everything (stack trace, current context, etc). Chrome is particularly good at that.